# How can I stop text to goes on next line on every space using flex property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.span {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#outerSender {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 40%;
}

#sender {
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  max-width: 400px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #99CC66;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#innerSender {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  right: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #009900;
  border: 1px solid #99CC66;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerSender">
  <div id="sender"><span class="span"></span>
    <div id="innerSender">fe wef wef ew wef</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use the flex property but the problem is that on every space between the text , it goes to new line.

How can I stop this?

Comment: Disabling `flex-basis` on `#innerSender` seems to resolve this-- is that the behavior you are looking for?  Or something different?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I want the text to start from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To right align the flex items, use `justify-content: flex-end`.

This won't work alone in your case, as your `span` is told to take full width, hence will push the `div` as far to the right as possible, and force line wrap.

One solution to that is to allow for the flex items to wrap, using `flex-wrap: wrap`

Stack snippet

```css
.span {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#outerSender {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 40%;
}

#sender {
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  max-width: 400px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;               /*  added  */
  border: 1px solid #99CC66;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 15px;
  justify-content: flex-end;     /*  added  */
}

#innerSender {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #009900;
  border: 1px solid #99CC66;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerSender">
  <div id="sender">
    <span class="span"></span>
    <div id="innerSender">fe wef wef ew wef</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="outerSender">
  <div id="sender">
    <span class="span"></span>
    <div id="innerSender">fe wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And if the `span` were there to accomplish the same, just remove it instead of using `flex-wrap`

Stack snippet

```css
#outerSender {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 40%;
}

#sender {
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  max-width: 400px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #99CC66;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 15px;
  justify-content: flex-end;     /*  added  */
}

#innerSender {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #009900;
  border: 1px solid #99CC66;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerSender">
  <div id="sender">
    <div id="innerSender">fe wef wef ew wef</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="outerSender">
  <div id="sender">
    <div id="innerSender">fe wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef wef wef ew wef</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But there is one problem , It cut the text after the width is fully cover.. I want the text on new line if full width is covered

Comment: @Rupesh So what is it you are trying to achieve, right aligned text that grows and then wrap, or what?

Comment: Yes exactly what you said.

Comment: same as any chatting text which start from right that grows and then wrap if its cover its full width.

Comment: @Rupesh Updated my answer

Comment: Thnx Man, You saved my lot of time.

Comment: @Rupesh Glad to help